# how to calculate total of column in JTable but started at particular index

Tags: java, swing

I have Amount column in JTable and one 'Total' and 'Final Total' button. So if I put 2 and 3 in amount column and hit 'Total' then i got 5 in another cell of same column.(My programm is worked fine till this step ) Now I want to  insert 3 and 4 below 5. I inserted and hit 'Final Total' then want to display only 12(5+3+4) in same column(Amount) at the last row. (5 is the answer which i got hitting total).
Here I paste my code of 'total' and 'Final Total' button. I am not sure about for loop using in 'Final Total' button. So please give solution for it.

```
    JButton total = new JButton("Total");
    total.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
                {
                    flag=1;
                    add.setEnabled(false);
                    Object source = ae.getSource();
                    if (source == total) 
                    { 
    model.addRow(new Object[]{new Integer(0),"TOTAL",new Integer(1), new Double(0.0),"",new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0)});
                        for( i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++)
                        {
                             amount = Double.parseDouble(model.getValueAt(i, 6).toString());
                             sum = new Double(sum+amount);
                         }
                        model.setValueAt(sum,model.getRowCount()-1,6);
                         }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"If you pressed Total then you can't select 'Add Row' button ");
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{new Integer(0),"",new Integer(0), new Double(0.0),"",new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0)});
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{new Integer(0),"",new Integer(0), new Double(0.0),"",new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0)});
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{new Integer(0),"",new Integer(0), new Double(0.0),"",new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0)});
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{new Integer(0),"",new Integer(0), new Double(0.0),"",new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0)});

                }
                });


    JButton btnFinalTotal = new JButton("Final total");
    btnFinalTotal.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                {
                    flag=2;
                    Object source = ae.getSource();
                    if (source == btnFinalTotal) 
                    {
                    d= Double.parseDouble(model.getValueAt(i,6).toString());
                    System.out.println("Current value of d is  "  +d);

                    model.addRow(new Object[]{new Integer(0),"FINAL TOTAL",new Integer(1), new Double(0.0),"",new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0)});
                        for(i=0;i>d;i++)
                        {
                            amount = Double.parseDouble(model.getValueAt(i, 6).toString());
                            finalamount= new Double(d+amount);
                        }  
                        model.setValueAt(finalamount,model.getRowCount()-1,6);
                    }
                }
            });

public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)
            {

                if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE)
                {
                    System.out.println("Cell " + e.getFirstRow() + ", "
                            + e.getColumn() + " changed. The new value: "
                            + table.getModel().getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(),
                                    e.getColumn()));
                    int row = e.getFirstRow();
                    int column = e.getColumn();
if(flag==1)
                    {
                         if(column == 6)
                         {
                        //   taxonamt= Double.parseDouble(model.getValueAt(row, 6).toString());
                             sum=Double.parseDouble(model.getValueAt(row, 6).toString());
                        //  Double total = new Double (sum*(taxonamt/100));
                             Double total = new Double (sum);
                             model.setValueAt(total,model.getRowCount()-1,7);
                         }
                    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to place some kind of "marker" into your data which designates a row as a "total" row, so you can find the last "total" row and calculate the rows below it.

Personally, I'd start with a plain old java object (POJO) which encapsulate the functionality you're aiming for and build the table model around it

Comment: Nope - that's something your going to have to try, you have all the information about the problem, any solution or code I make ultimately won't meet your over all needs/requirements. I've done it in the past and wasted days of effort for it - also, SO is not a code factory. My suggestion is, try something, you'll need to use AbstractTableModel to be able to support your customised object